# Formatting a date field in Drupal rules

Tags: rules

Is there a way to format a date in Drupal rules? I've got a date timestamp, but obviously that's less than ideal for a client-facing situation.

How do you change a field to a different sort of formatting while in the rules UI?

Comment: Is this `date timestamp` a component?

Comment: It's a date field from a node.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `[node:field_calendar_date:custom:l, Fd, gia]`? Custom being whatever date format you set up. (like the presets: short, medium, long)

Make sense?

Comment: I tried to do this, and it just showed me the plan text of the above. I don't think I tried custom though. Let me check that.

Comment: [entity-fetched:field_date_time_3:custom:Medium] is what I get.